# Getting instagram post url from media id

Tags: api, instagram

I have the post **media_id** in my hands and I'd like to know if there is a way to create a valid url from it.

For instance, if you have a Facebook post id (xxxx_yyyy) on your hands, you can create the following url from it (http://facebook.com/**xxxx**/posts/**yyyy**) and directly access the original post.

Is there a way to do this on Instagram? Having media_id (and user_id) in my hands, is it possible to create a single post url?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to implement client side javascript to solve this and Seano's answer was invaluable and I was glad they mentioned the use of the BigInteger library however I wanted to provide a complete implementation using the BigInteger library which as it turns out is quite necessary.

I downloaded the BigInteger lib from https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer.

Here is the function which works well for me.

```
function getInstagramUrlFromMediaId(media_id) {
    var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
    var shortenedId = '';
    media_id = media_id.substring(0, media_id.indexOf('_'));

    while (media_id > 0) {
        var remainder = bigInt(media_id).mod(64);
        media_id = bigInt(media_id).minus(remainder).divide(64).toString();
        shortenedId = alphabet.charAt(remainder) + shortenedId;
    }

    return 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + shortenedId + '/';
}
```

I just want to point out that the usage of toString() when assigning the re-calculated media_id is very important, the value remains a string to ensure the entire number is used (in my case the media_id was 19 characters long).  The BigInteger documentation also states this...

> Note that Javascript numbers larger than 9007199254740992 and smaller than -9007199254740992 are not precisely represented numbers and will not produce exact results. If you are dealing with numbers outside that range, it is better to pass in strings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled across this question, all the solutions are great, but none of them were in a language I use often, so running the code would have been a pain in the ass for me.

Seeing that Python is everywhere, I ported over @seano's answer:

```
def getInstagramUrlFromMediaId(media_id):
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    shortened_id = ''

    while media_id > 0:
        remainder = media_id % 64
        # dual conversion sign gets the right ID for new posts
        media_id = (media_id - remainder) // 64;
        # remainder should be casted as an integer to avoid a type error. 
        shortened_id = alphabet[int(remainder)] + shortened_id

    return 'https://instagram.com/p/' + shortened_id + '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would be possible using the following endpoint one of the `media endpoints`:

Here is a small php script that will get the link based on `media_id` and `user_id`:

```
$media_id = 'media_id';
$user_id = 'user_id';
$client_id = 'instagram_client_id';
$client_secret = 'instagram_client_secret';
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{$media_id}_{$user_id}?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);
if (is_object($response)) {
  $link_to_media = $response->data->link;
}
```

In the above example you should replace the `media_id`, `user_id`, `client_id`, `client_secret` with their appropriate values. You should also be able to use an `access_token` instead of `client_id` and `client_secret` as in this example.

**References**

[Media Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media)

Answer (score 1):

You can also figure it out algorithmically. It can be done in any language, but here is a way via MySQL function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS url_fragment

DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION url_fragment(PID BIGINT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE ALPHA CHAR(64);
DECLARE SHORTCODE VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE MEDIAID BIGINT;
DECLARE REMAINDER INT;

SET ALPHA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
SET MEDIAID = SUBSTRING_INDEX(PID, "_", 1);


WHILE MEDIAID > 0 DO
    SET REMAINDER = MOD(MEDIAID, 64);
    SET MEDIAID = (MEDIAID - REMAINDER) / 64;
    SET SHORTCODE = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ALPHA, (REMAINDER + 1), 1), SHORTCODE);
END WHILE;

RETURN SHORTCODE;

END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to make sure you provide it only the post_id and not the user_id. If you are storing the id by default as instagram gives it to you, it should already be in the form 'postId_userId' which is why SUBSTRING_INDEX(PID, "_", 1) is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to derive the URL segment from the media ID using JavaScript:

```
function getInstagramUrlFromMediaId(media_id) {
    media_id = parseInt(media_id.substring(0, media_id.indexOf('_')));
    var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
    var shortenedId = '';
    while (media_id > 0) {
        var remainder = modulo(media_id % 64);
        media_id = (media_id - remainder) / 64;
        shortenedId = alphabet.charAt(remainder) + shortenedId;
    }
    return 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + shortenedId + '/';
}
```

Depending on how old the Instagram post is, you may need to use a library like [BigInteger](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger/tree/master) to handle the larger IDs.

You can find a breakdown of the encoding between media id and url segment here: http://carrot.is/coding/instagram-ids

Answer (score 1):

The instagram API returns a "shortcode" property.  Something simple like this could work for you.

`post.Link = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + media.shortcode;`

Answer (score 0):

I made Nick's answer use the `BigInt` that ships with Node. I also avoid returning the full url, I just return the shortcode.

```
function getInstagramShortcodeFromId(media_id) {
  const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
  let shortenedId = '';

  while (media_id > 0) {
    const remainder = BigInt(media_id) % BigInt(64);
    media_id = ((BigInt(media_id) - BigInt(remainder)) / BigInt(64)).toString();
    shortenedId = alphabet.charAt(Number(remainder)) + shortenedId;
  }

  return shortenedId;
}
```