# Instagram: Get oEmbed using Media ID

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Say, I have a media ID (eg. 1075297042445691366_195350057). How to get the Embed HTML using the oEmbed API?

[This API](https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed) accepts only shortcode (which is different from media ID).

Or How to get the shortcode of an media ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any media object returned by the API has a field called 'link' that is the URL representation of the media. You can use this link as 'url' parameter of the oembed endpoint.

Comment: The OP doesn't have the link or the URL, they have a media ID. How do you convert that media ID into a link/URL/shortcode? Not sure why this was checkmarked because it does not solve or answer the question at all(unless I'm misreading?)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this question in the future I spent quite a while trying to solve it.

This implementation deserves 99.9% credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47423595/477958) by Nick Hanshaw. All I did was include a CDN link to the BigInteger.js library which is required, but not part of Nick's code. This is currently working for me right now by passing the Media ID as a string into the function, then returning the full string of the Instagram photo URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.40/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getInstagramUrlFromMediaId(media_id) {
        var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
        var shortenedId = '';
        media_id = media_id.substring(0, media_id.indexOf('_'));

        while (media_id > 0) {
            var remainder = bigInt(media_id).mod(64);
            media_id = bigInt(media_id).minus(remainder).divide(64).toString();
            shortenedId = alphabet.charAt(remainder) + shortenedId;
        }

        return 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + shortenedId + '/';
    }
</script>
```